# How do i match posted browser URL id with PHP, Mysql using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I'm developing Web-Application into PHP & MYSQL using ANgular JS.

**please refer below code**

```
dhmsApp.controller('dhmsDetailsView',function($scope,$http, $routeParams){
var userId = $routeParams.id;
console.log(userId);
```

});

writing above code i got posted Browser URL id. please check with below screen-shot for your reference.

[image]

Problem is : 
How do i match or how do i write condition for above fetched user ID into Controller using PHP, MySql and angular js

Comment: Which router are you using? This is explained in the documentation for the various routers

Comment: When you say "how do I match", what do you mean exactly? Are you trying to pass the ID query parameter from your Angular app to the server? Or are you trying to have the server fill in the ID query parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by match? What do you really want to do?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass this variable to server using [angular resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and you can use this [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) which creates rest api.

Comment: i think this is what you need as per your comment in the answer given by @geo-paul 
you can use angular resource to send the id to the php script which can then be used in the mysql where statement.

Comment: HI @shantanu can you lease help me out i'm still stuck at this issue

Comment: @Harshad can you be more specific on what do you want to match?

Answer (score -2):

So basically you got the ID. Now I think you can make a php rest endpoint which takes in this IP and returns JSON Data related to that ID.

and you can do the rest processing of JSON Data in Angular(Client)

Comment: Thank you for reverting.
Could you please provide some example.

Comment: hmm.. okay. are you comfortable creating rest endpoints in PHP?

Comment: No... but i know to wrtie PHP code and MySql queries.
i know the logic behind it. but i don't know how write code in angular.
like, i got posted ID using Angular js, what i need is, that ID..... i need to pass in where condition of MySql query.

Comment: Please check with it ....... 


dhmsApp.controller('dhmsDetailsView',function($scope,$http, $routeParams){
    var userId = $routeParams.id;
    console.log(userId);
    $.ajax({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        type: 'application/json',
        url: 'pages/detailsView.php', 
        data: { userId: userId}, 
        success: function (response) { 
            $scope.names = response; 
        } 
    });
});

in php file how will i echo this ID